# Android OpenGL application crashes after few onDrawFrame calls

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am programming little application for android in OpenGL ES 2.0. Everything was going fine, but today I implemented 2D text drawing. I just create normal canvas, write text on it and then I just load this bitmap as 2D Texture and draw it. This is method I use to change the value of the text.

```
public void setText(String text){
    if(!this.text.equals(text)){
        this.text = text;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        bitmap.eraseColor(0);
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(32);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bounds.height(), textPaint);
        GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, new int[]{textureHandle}, 0);
        this.setTexture(bitmap);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

I wanted to try it out, so I started to count amount of onDrawFrame calls. It works well, but at the 1045th call it freezes, then it continues for a few more frames and then the app just crashes.

I concluded, that it may be happening because of lack of free memory so I added GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, new int[]{textureHandle}, 0); to free unnecessary texture from memory, but it haven't change anything.

Any ideas where might be problem?

Thanks Toneks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setText() is being called by a different thread than the rest of your OpenGL ES code, then that is the problem.  All call to OpenGL ES must be made from a single thread on Android.  This article gives more detail on this:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1